# How to have slider continuously play without pausing

Tags: zurb-foundation, orbit

I am using the Foundation Orbit slider to have a content slider without images on a homepage for the site I am developing. I was wondering if there is any way of forcing the slider to continuously play without pausing at all. Right now it is pausing on click and I have pause_on_hover set to false.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the following to your stylesheet along with `pause_on_hover:false;` in `data-options`:

```
.orbit-timer {
    display:none;
}
```

It will completely hide the progress bar but it will also prevent the slider from stopping even if someone clicks it, it will just be on a continuous loop.

Answer (score -1):

this issue is resolved, please update your foundation.orbit.js with this new js

https://github.com/NikhilKalige/foundation/blob/1cb1da0660a69296715fb764e082190aa07df6da/js/foundation/foundation.orbit.js

**or**

add this in your foundation.min.js
**,r.start()**

Just look for **r.update_progress(0)** in your foundation.min.js and append this **,r.start()**

final code snippets will look like this

**,r.update_progress(0)/*addition*/,r.start()/*done*/},this.start**